# Debugging shared library .so with JNI using gdb

Tags: c++, c, linux, gdb, .so

I have java application which is calling c/cpp code (it is .so files) using JNI.
I am using API's from this .so files. I have to debug .so files, how to debug it?

I tried below things:

1. I attached gdb to xyz.so and add breakpoints.
2. run java code

but not able to hit breakpoint.
can you suggest how to debug it.
after breakpoint, I can not run r or c (continue).

so how can we debug in such case?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you compile something, as output, you have *assembly code* (which is run by the computer) and the *symbols* (which are the association between your source code and the assembly code).

In order to debug the C/C++ part, you must have the appropriate *symbols* in order to be able to place a break point with the same user experience you have in java. Otherwise, you'll just see a huge sequence of numbers and what you are doing is actually *reverse engineering* the code.

Therefore, you need the symbols which are not shipped by default (you should ask the vendor if they can provide them).

Comment: The issue with C++ code invoked from Java is that it is usually not visible from java. These .so files are loaded dynamically at run time

Comment: Java native debuggers cannot see what is "non java". Debuggers capable of handling other languages as well, like C++, will be able to show a better picture provided the symbols are available. Debuggers can load symbols as soon as their corresponding code unit is loaded, if they are able to locate them. If you manage to get the symbols and store them in the symbol path, the debugger will use them.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.
I tried this and it worked
attached java process to gdb
added bteakpoints to cope which is in cpp module
press c (gdb continue cmd)
gdb stopped at break point